# How whip antenna even work if they don't have two terminals?

Tags: signal-detection

I understand antenna should have two terminals to emit radio waves like this:

[image]

But in whip antenna it has only one pointy terminal, how does it work?

Comment: this is off topic here.  but my understanding of a quarter-wave vertical antenna, fed from the bottom is that the other terminal is connected to the ground plane.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because antenna design and theory questions are generally electrical engineering, but not signal processing (as commonly understood). Hence, this is off-topic, but might have answers on http://electronics.stackexchange.com ; check whether there's not already an answer to your question there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whip antennas must work against a ground plane.  If it's a whip antenna built into a handheld radio, the radio body (and you) act as the ground plane.  If you're building a vertical whip antenna, it's common to provide a ground plane [from ARRL](https://www.arrl.org/files/file/Technology/tis/info/pdf/ab18-16.pdf):

[image: 1/4 wave whip, from ARRL]